# Can substituting beets with other nitrate rich vegetables to improve athletic performance?

Tags: nutrition, food, vegetables

Beet roots have been known to improve endurance and reduce oxygen consumption during exercise.

Can other nitrate rich vegetables produce similar effects?

Studies seem to focus mainly on beets for athletic performance. Other vegetables 
can be a good source of nitrates. If the test subjects drank swiss chard juice or beet green juice, can we be confident that it would be as effective as beet root juice?

Here's a table showing the nitrate content of vegetables.

[image]

Comment: A quick review suggest so, but nothing that I could turn into a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

**NITRATE FROM NON-BEET SOURCES**

Here is one very small study in 7 young men, in whom diet rich in spinach and collard greens, but not beetroot, high in nitrates (~510 mg or 8.2 mmol per day) for 6 days was associated with increased physical performance: [Effects of a Short-Term High-Nitrate Diet on Exercise Performance (Nutrients, 2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5037521/)

> In conclusion, this study has shown that the ingestion of nitrate-rich
>   foods can increase plasma nitrate/nitrite concentrations and improve
>   exercise performance. In particular, this nutritional intervention
>   reduced energy demand during moderate-intensity exercise, enhanced
>   muscle work during fatiguing intermittent submaximal contractions, and
>   improved repeated sprint performance, whereas maximal isometric force
>   or peak power output were not affected.

In another very small study in 9 young men, adding sodium nitrate supplements (~465 mg or 7.5 mmol nitrate per day) for 3 days was associated with increased physical performance: [Effects of dietary nitrate on oxygen cost during exercise (Acta Physiologica, 2009)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1748-1716.2007.01713.x):

> We conclude that dietary nitrate supplementation, in an amount
>   achievable through a diet rich in vegetables, results in a lower
>   oxygen demand during submaximal work.

**NITRATE FROM BEETROOT JUICE**

[Effects of Beetroot Juice Supplementation on Cardiorespiratory Endurance in Athletes. A Systematic Review (Nutrients, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5295087/):

> - Acute supplementation with beetroot juice may have an ergogenic effect on reducing VO2 at less than or equal to VO2max intensity,
>     while improving the relationship between watts required and VO2 level,
>     mechanisms that make it possible to enable increase time-to-exhaustion
>     at less than or equal to VO2max intensity.
> - Apparently, the effects of supplementation with beetroot juice might not have a positive interaction with caffeine supplementation,
>     mitigating the effects of beetroot juice intake on cardiorespiratory
>     performance.
> - Intake of beetroot juice should be initiated within 90 min before athletic effort, since the peak value of NO3− occurs within 2–3 h
>     after ingestion. At least 6–8 mmol [370-500 mg] of NO3− intake is required, which
>     can be increased in athletes with a high level of training.

Another review of studies with nitrate added as beetroot juice or sodium nitrate:

[Nitrate Ingestion: A Review of the Health and Physical Performance Effects (Nutrients, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4245587/):

> This review focused primarily on the impact of dietary nitrate to aid
>   physical performance and covered 31 studies, inclusive of over 300
>   participants. Quantitative analysis suggests that **performance
>   enhancing benefits** are noted predominately with **doses ranging from
>   5 to 9 mmol of NO3−,** delivered as either a single bolus or as
>   multiple (e.g., 1–15) daily servings of said dosage ingestion. This
>   correlates to about **500 mL (~2 cups) of BRJ** (~5–9 mmol of NO3−) at
>   each dosing, with peak **elevations in plasma NO2− resulting 2.5 and 3
>   h post-ingestion.** These peak plasma NO2− concentrations appear to
>   directly correlate with peak reductions in systolic and diastolic
>   blood pressure and may be related to peak physical performance as
>   well. Benefits have been noted with up to 15 days of chronic NO3−
>   supplementation and appear to persist 24 h post-ingestion. No
>   additional benefits have been noted by increasing NO3− concentration
>   above 8.4 mmol and up to 18.1 mmol of NO3−, although further research
>   is needed in this area.

Other studies with beetroot juice:

- [Dietary Nitrate and Physical Performance (Annual Review of Nutrition, 2018)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30130468)
- [Beetroot Juice Supplementation Improves High-Intensity Intermittent Type Exercise Performance in Trained Soccer Players (Nutrients, 2107)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5372977/):

[Food sources of nitrates and nitrites: the physiologic context for potential health benefits (The American Journal of Clinical Nutrition, 2009)](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/90/1/1/4596750)

**FOODS HIGH IN NITRATE (mg nitrate/100 g fresh food):**

- 100-250: celeriac, Chinese cabbage, endive, fennel, kohlrabi, leek, parsley
- 250+: celery, cress, chervil, lettuce, red beetroot, spinach, rocket (rucola, arugula)

**CONCLUSION**

Larger studies are needed to provide stronger evidence that nitrate as such, and not other nutrients in food, increase physical performance.